# Preserving ratios in responsive menu

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, flexbox

I'm trying to create a responsive menu with tiles.

- Depending on content, it could contain **up to 8 tiles**.
- It will change shape at certain breakpoints. At 8 tiles, it starts at 4x2 on small screens, changes to 1x8 at medium and ends at 2x4 at large ones.
- Each tile needs to be 150px wide and 105px high, with a small gutter inbetween them (2px in this example). On screens, where such dimensions can't fit anymore, they should **shrink proportionally**, retaining the layout structure (**4x2**).

The example below succeeds in the menu and it's tiles starting to shrink (widht-wise) when the viewport gets too narrow, but it fails at shrinking the tiles proportionally. I've tried fiddling around with *width*, *max-width*, *height*, *max-height* on all layers, the *height: auto;* property. Nothing worked.

I've based the menu on *flexbox's wrap property*, because it allows me to change the grid layout at breakpoints without compromising the HTML structure and I want to avoid using CSS grid due insufficient browser support.

**Important: Expand the snipped to full screen to observe the shrinking effect.**

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tile-group {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 608px;
}

.tile-padding {
  width: 152px;
  height: 107px;
  padding: 1px;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.tile {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.tile-color-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.tile-color-2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.tile-color-3 {
  background-color: green;
}

.tile-color-4 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.tile-color-5 {
  background-color: indianred;
}

.tile-color-6 {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.tile-color-7 {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}

.tile-color-8 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile-group">
  <div class="tile-padding">
    <div class="tile tile-color-1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile-padding">
    <div class="tile tile-color-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile-padding">
    <div class="tile tile-color-3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile-padding">
    <div class="tile tile-color-4"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile-padding">
    <div class="tile tile-color-5"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile-padding">
    <div class="tile tile-color-6"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile-padding">
    <div class="tile tile-color-7"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile-padding">
    <div class="tile tile-color-8"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess it should be .tile-padding { width:25%; max-width: 152px;}